# jaxb adding namespace to element

Tags: web-services, soap, jaxb, wsdl

According to my task I have to invoke SOAP service. So, I have generated java classes from wsdl using xjc. But I have a problem invoking SOAP service. My application generates this request:

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/><soap:Body>
<typ:SendMessage xmlns:ns4="http://test.user.kz/UserInfo" xmlns:q1="http://test.user.kz/CustomerInfo" xmlns:typ="http://test.user.kz/MyChannel/v1/Types">
    <request>
        <requestInfo>
            <messageId>26e96b11-8f82-421e-829a</messageId>
        </requestInfo>
        <requestData>
            <data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="q1:PaymentPackageRequestType">
                <q1:methodName>testMethod</q1:methodName>
            </data>
        </requestData>
    </request>
</typ:SendMessage></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

But I need in my SOAP request I need to specify namespace in data tag, lik this:

```
     <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/><soap:Body>
<typ:SendMessage xmlns:ns4="http://test.user.kz/UserInfo" xmlns:q1="http://test.user.kz/CustomerInfo" xmlns:typ="http://test.user.kz/MyChannel/v1/Types">
    <request>
        <requestInfo>
            <messageId>26e96b11-8f82-421e-829a</messageId>
        </requestInfo>
        <requestData>
                        <data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:type="q1:PaymentPackageRequestType"  **xmlns:q1="http://payments.bee.kz/PaymentPackage"**>
                <q1:methodName>testMethod</q1:methodName>
            </data>
        </requestData>
    </request>
</typ:SendMessage></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Otherwise target SOAP service gives me error:

```
XML namespace prefix 'q1' is not defined.
```

How it possible to specify namespace in data tag?
This is my current package-info:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
        xmlns = {
            @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "typ",
                    namespaceURI = "http://test.user.kz/MyChannel/v1/Types"),
            @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "q1",
                    namespaceURI = "http://test.user.kz/CustomerInfo")
        },
   elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED,
   attributeFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.UNSET
)
package kz.uni.gen;
```

So I couldn't add namespace xmlns:q1="http://test.user.kz/CustomerInfo" to data tag in SOAP request. How can I add this namespace declaration or move namespace declaration from SendMessage tag?

Answer (score 0):

so using JAXB it is not possible. Therefore I am manually added namespace in required element. This is full snippet:

```
Document document = null;
        try {
            document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
            Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(SendMessage.class).createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
            marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.characterEscapeHandler", new CharacterEscapeHandler() {
                @Override
                public void escape(char[] buf, int start, int len, boolean b, Writer out) throws IOException {
                    out.write(buf, start, len);
                }
            });
            QName name = new QName(NAMESPACE_URI, SendMessage.class.getSimpleName());
            JAXBElement<SendMessage> root = new JAXBElement<SendMessage>(name, SendMessage.class, from);
            StringWriter writer1 = new StringWriter();
            marshaller.marshal(root, writer1);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
            Element node = dbf
                    .newDocumentBuilder()
                    .parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(writer1.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)))
                    .getDocumentElement();
            Attr attr1 = document.createAttribute("xmlns:q1");
            attr1.setValue("http://test.user.kz/CustomerInfo");
            node.getElementsByTagName("data").item(0).getAttributes().setNamedItem(node.getOwnerDocument().importNode(attr1, true));
            return node;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Unable to transform POJO to XML SOAP message ", e);

        }
```